# my submit button for my web form keep sending false

Tags: php, html

this is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Web</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <form method="POST">
            Username<input type="text" name="username">
            Password<input type="password" name="password">
            <input type="Submit" name="submit" id="sub">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($username == 'username' && $password == 'password') {
        echo "berhasil";
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid Username / Password";
    }
}


?>
```

[image]

but every time i reload the page without doing anything it keep echoing invalid username / password even though i never press the button

i expect when i press the submit button then it tells me either correct or not

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "sending false"? You could inspect `$_POST` by dumping it

Comment: I think the problem is echo "berhasil";

Comment: @MarcusPetersen - I think you need to be more specific.

Comment: If you keep pressing refresh after submitting, it will try to resubmit the form. Better to load the page again from scratch to get a more realistic experience

Comment: _"but every time i reload the page without doing anything it keep echoing invalid username / password even though i never press the button"_ - are you saying your browser did _not_ ask you, whether you wanted to repeat the POST request you already made, and sent the same data again ...? It should, in this situation. If not, then I guess you must have somehow disabled that at some point.

Comment: Can you run `print_r($_POST);` before the `if`? And what's the output?

Comment: Also NEVER call anything in a form `name="submit"` or `id="submit"` since it hides the submit event from JavaScript. It is just something to remember for another day.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this check and paste your code into the if condition.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($username === 'username' && $password === 'password') {
            echo "berhasil";
        } else {
            echo "Invalid Username / Password";
        }
    }
}
?>
```